# Is there a way to use constructors of one type as types too?

Tags: haskell

For example:

```
data Foo = Bar Int | Baz String
```

I would like to use a function like:

```
qux :: [Foo] -> [Baz]
qux fs = filter f fs
    where
        f (Baz _) = True
        f _ = False
```

Normally, i need to:

```
data Bar = Bar Int
data Baz = Baz String

data Foo = FBar Bar | FBaz Baz

qux = ...
```

but I'm not happy with this solution, because it needs lots of redundant code.

Is there a elegant way to solve this issue?

Comment: Why not just do `qux :: [Foo] -> [String]`?  If the actual `Baz` has multiple fields, make them into a tuple.

Comment: There is not a way to use contructors like that, Haskell keeps two distinct namespaces for types and constructors.  You could just have `qux` have the type `[Foo] -> [Foo]`, and then you're guaranteed the correct behavior, just not compiler enforced.  If you want that distinction at the type level, they _must_ be separate types.

Comment: @jwodder Its just a example. I have more complex and flexible structures, where i could need this. Tuples are a way too ugly, when used on big structures.

Comment: You can do something like this with GADTs.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to use [GADTs](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT). The gist of it is that this allows us to have a so-called ["phantom" type argument](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Phantom_type) to a data type definition. One thing we can do with this is restrict the type of a function (for instance) that uses this data type so that it only works with values that could be created by a certain constructor.

Here is how I would write the example you gave in this style (Note: You need to have the GADTs extension enabled):

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
data BarType -- Note: These could be called Bar and Baz, but I named them this for clarity
data BazType

data Foo a where
    Bar :: Int -> Foo BarType
    Baz :: Int -> Foo BazType
```

With this, you can write functions like this:

```
onlyAcceptsBars :: Foo BarType -> Int
onlyAcceptsBars (Bar bar) = -- ...
-- There would be a compile-time error if you had a case like this:
--    onlyAcceptsBars (Baz baz) = ...

onlyAcceptsBazs :: Foo BazType -> Int
onlyAcceptsBazs (Baz baz) = -- ...

acceptsAnyFoo :: Foo a -> Int
acceptsAnyFoo (Bar bar) = -- ...
acceptsAnyFoo (Baz baz) = -- ...
```

Comment: You could even use `DataKinds` to use `Bar` and `Baz` as the types themselves.

Comment: Doesn't allow you to mix them however, there's no `[Bar 1, Baz 2]`

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do exactly what you want. Let's take the following example

```
data Foo = Bar Int String | Baz Bool Int

isBaz (Baz _ _) = True
isBaz  _        = False
```

To achieve what you want, you have essentially three options. First, filter without bothering to change the type

```
qux :: [Foo] -> [Foo]
qux = filter isBaz
```

Alternatively, you can turn your `Foo`s into tuples

```
qux :: [Foo] -> [(Bool, Int)]
qux = map f . filter isBaz
  where
    f (Baz b i) = (b,i)
```

Or you can define a new type

```
data Baz' = Baz' Bool Int

qux :: [Foo] -> [Baz']
qux = map f . filter isBaz
  where
    f (Baz b i) = Baz' b i
```

Or you can rewrite `Foo` as you suggested in your question

```
data Bar = Bar Int String
data Baz = Baz Bool Int
data Foo = FooBar Bar | FooBaz Baz

isBaz (FooBaz _) = True
isBaz  _         = False

qux :: [Foo] -> [Baz]
qux = map f . filter isBaz
  where
    f (FooBaz baz) = baz
```

Hopefully you find one of these acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me as if you're making an analogy between these two things:

1. The type constructor `Foo` and its variant constructors `Bar` and `Baz`;
2. An object-oriented type `Foo` and its subtypes `Bar` and `Baz`.

Haskell doesn't work that way at all.  No type is ever a subtype or supertype of any other; type constructors like `Foo` and value constructors like `Bar`/`Baz` are completely separate entities.

There are several things you can try to do here.  The first and simplest one is what jwodder suggests in a comment: write a `[Foo] -> [String]`.  This has the virtue of being simple and direct, with the disadvantage that you may want a type that's not `String`.

A variant of this is to define types `Bar` and `Baz` separate from `Foo`, and define `Foo` in terms of these:

```
newtype Bar = Bar Int
newtype Baz = Baz String
data Foo = ABar Bar | ABaz Baz
```

This now has the virtue that you can't use a plain `String` where a `Baz` is expected; the downside is that it's noticeably more verbose, but you can write helper functions to make things briefer:

```
-- Virtual constructors for `Foo`
bar :: Int -> Foo
bar i = ABar (Bar i)

baz :: String -> Foo
baz s = ABaz (Baz s)

-- A helper function to do the pattern matching for you.  You give it a pair of
-- functions, one telling it how to process the `Int` in a `Bar`, the other how 
-- to process the `String` in a `Baz`. 
analyzeFoo :: (Int -> r) -> (String -> r) -> Foo -> r
analyzeFoo barCase bazCase (ABar (Bar i) = barCase i
analyzeFoo barCase bazCase (ABaz (Baz s) = bazCase s
```

Then there are the more advanced solutions, which perhaps you shouldn't worry about.  David Young's uses GADTs and empty types to tag the `Foo` type to indicate what type of element it carries, so that `Foo BarType` can only be constructed with `Bar`, and `Foo BazType` only with `Baz`.

Another advanced solution goes this way: first, you parametrize your `Foo` type so that instead of `Int` and `String` you have type variables:

```
data Foo a b = Bar a | Baz b
```

Now, one way of specializing this type so that it can only be the `Baz` case is to instantiate type variable `a` to a type that contains no values; if `a` has no values, then you can't hit the `Bar` case unless the program errors out or runs forever.

The [`void`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/void-0.6.1/docs/Data-Void.html) library comes with such a type, called `Void`.  Using that:

```
import Data.Void

data Foo' a b = Bar a | Baz b

type Foo = Foo' Int String
type Bar = Foo' Int Void
type Baz = Foo Void String

qux :: [Foo] -> [Baz]
qux = concatMap f
    where f (Bar i) = []
          f (Baz s) = [Baz s]

example :: [Baz] -> [Baz]
example = map go
    where go (Bar v) = absurd v        -- can't happen, no value exists for `v`
          go (Baz s) = Baz (s ++ "!")
```

The trick here is that the type `Foo' Void String` basically means "either a `Bar` that contains something that doesn't exist (`Void`), or a `Baz` that contains a `String`."  Which means that it must be the latter.

Answer (score 1):

With list comprehensions,

```
qux fs = [Baz x | Baz x <- fs]
```

though the type stays the same, while you want an automatic "subtype downcast". Or, define

```
foo bar baz v | Bar x <- v = bar x | Baz y <- v = baz y

qux fs = filter (foo (const False) (const True)) fs
```

but I suspect that you want more complex subcase choices, like in case with more than two variants, accept all but one. The *type analyzer* function `foo` will help you with that too. Luis Casillas mentions it too, but in more complex setting. It can just be used with your original type, unaltered.

But, again, the result type stays the same, unlike what you wanted. If you must have type-level distinction for `qux`'s results, you can just tag *them*, leaving `Foo` as is:

```
newtype Baz a = Baz' a
newtype Bar a = Bar' a

qux :: [Foo] -> Baz [Foo]
qux = Baz' . filter (foo (const False) (const True))
```

Or you could push `Baz'` inside the list, with `qux :: [Foo] -> [Baz Foo]; qux = map Baz' . filter ...`. In any case the type analyzer function approach is helpful.